# PHPDocumentor broken links

Tags: php, linux, phpdoc

The links in the responsive phpdocumentor template seem to be broken. For example the url to the packages contains 'db_Models' packages/db_Models/ When removing db_Models from the URL it work fine.
Also breadcrumbs are broken as they are including forward and backslashes 
'/packages/db_Models\'

I'm using Ubuntu and installed phpDoc via apt-get
All dependencies for phpDocumentor are met.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by un-installing phpDoc and reinstalling it via PHP Pear.